# Uncaught Action failed error with lightning:recordViewForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordviewform

I have a use case in which I need to the display the address fields(all custom fields with the same API name in both objects) of lead/ Account. Let's say if I'm on Enquiry object(custom object) then fetch the address details from lead else if I'm on Opportunity record page then fetch details from Accounts.

Here is my Component code

```
<aura:component controller="AESL_CommonUpdateAddressCtrl"
                implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name ="objName" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="title" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objAddress" type="sObject"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <Lightning:Card class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner" 
                    title="{!v.title}">

        <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="{!v.objName}">
        <div class="slds-box">
            <span>These fields should not have a label</span>
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="AESL_State__c" />
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="AESL_City__c" />
        </div>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
    </Lightning:Card>
</aura:component>
```

My helper's init method is

```
getAddress.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state= response.getState();
            if(state==='SUCCESS'){
                var address = response.getReturnValue()
                if(!$A.util.isEmpty(address)){

                    alert(JSON.stringify(address));
                    component.set('v.recordId',address[0]);
                    component.set('v.objName',address[1]);
                    if(address[1] === 'Lead'){
                        component.set('v.title','Lead Address Information');
                    }
                    else{
                        component.set('v.title','Student Address Information');
                    }
                }
```

It's giving an error

> Uncaught Action failed:
>   lightning:recordViewForm$controller$handleRecordIdChange [Cannot read
>   property 'getList' of null] Callback failed:
>   apex://AESL_CommonUpdateAddressCtrl/ACTION$getObjectId

I tried to use breakpoints where the code is throwing this error. At
`component.set('v.recordId',address[0]);` line it get redirected to `aura_prod.js`
Please correct me if I'm doing something wrong? or is it possible to achieve the scenario with this approach?

Comment: 1 more thing, I tried the same code with fixed recordId and API name(Lead) on Enquiry record Page. Then it's running fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different things and experiments I came to the solution of the problem. Here is what I did

Instead of using

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="{!v.objName}">
        <div class="slds-box">
            <span>These fields should not have a label</span>
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="AESL_State__c" />
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="AESL_City__c" />
        </div>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
```

I used this

```
<lightning:recordForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              objectApiName="{!v.objName}"
                              fields="{!v.leadfield}"
                              mode="view"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(address));
```

should be showing you that for some cases your server-side is not returning an array (i.e. the `alert` output does not start with the array token `[`).

Being not empty is not the same as being an array so this isn't too useful:

```
if(!$A.util.isEmpty(address)){
```

(You can see the implementation of the various `$A.util` functions in the open source for [Util.js](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/400b2dcabfe704b972fecc1b41e1ce38336864c0/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/util/Util.js)).

**PS**

Looking at the error message you quote more carefully, it looks like this code is working:

```
component.set('v.recordId',address[0]);
```

but the problem is arising in this component:

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"  objectApiName="{!v.objName}">
```

when the record Id changes. That probably leaves the component with `recordId` set to one object type and a `objectApiName` set to a different object type. It might be necessary to dynamically recreate the `lightning:recordViewForm` if you can't find an order to update those attributes that works.

Comment: Hi @Keith, I have not encountered any cases yet in which the server is returning something and the alert message is not displayed. Also, I'm using alert just to pop-up the value returned from the server and will be removed from the final code.

Comment: @VDahiya I'm saying that I think that when your code goes wrong the server is not returning an array. Can you add to your question the exact output of the `alert` when you get the error?

Comment: ["00QK000000B50FWMAZ","Lead"] alert output when error is thrown.

Comment: @VDahiya Yeah weird. Does `$A.util.isArray(address)` return true? Suggest using your browser's JavaScript debugger would make sense; see e.g. http://peterknolle.com/lightning-component-debugging-tips/.

Comment: Yeap $A.util.isArray(address) returned true in case of error also.

Comment: @VDahiya See the **PS** I just added to my answer.

Comment: I have implemented the same scenario with lightning:editForm also and that's working fine. And I think as both of these i.e.(editForm and recordViewForm) need recordId and ObjectAPIName but editForm working fine then it also supposed to work. Hence I don't think (but not sure) recordId and objectAPIname and not in sync.

Comment: Also, If I'm not wrong,  page loads after init stop its execution. Hence recordViewForm should be loaded after init call, leaving no scope of unrelated  recordId and objectAPI name.(Please correct me if 'm wrong)

Comment: @VDahiya You know more about this than me. The error looks like it's in `lightning:recordViewForm`; I recommend using the JavaScript debugger to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently, and found a solution.

Please make sure your recordId has a correct value. You can do aura:if to check recordId before render ligthning:recordViewForm